# Combine 2 queries (different columns from 2 different sheets) and filter based on matching results

Tags: google-sheets

As usual, I have set a goal, way beyond my skills...

I need to get data from 2 sheets, One has a lot more entries than the other (a master list I guess you could say). Any entry in the smaller sheet will always have a matching entry in the Master, but not necessarily the other way round.

I have written what I need in pseudo query syntax, but I need help getting this to work...

```
QUERY the 'Catalog' sheet and get TITLE, SUBTITLE, STATUS, TITLE-ID WHERE the STATUS does NOT have the word 'Retired' in it.
Then Query 'Report_Dec 2017' and get UNITS, USD, GPB, EUR WHERE TITLE-ID from 'Report_Dec 2017' Matches TITLE-ID from 'Catalog'

Catalog (master)
  | TITLE | SUBTITLE | STATUS | TITLE-ID |   

Report_Nov_2017
  | UNITS | USD | GPB | EUR |  (has TITLE-ID also, but don't need this twice) 

Final result should look like this:

 | TITLE | SUBTITLE | STATUS | TITLE-ID | UNITS | USD | GPB  | EUR |
```

The end result should only ever have a max number of entries equal to that of from 'Report_Nov 2017', So the Catalog might have 100 total entries but since only 20 units were sold in November, then the result will only show 20

First of all is that possible? And secondly, if it is, can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT UPDATE**

I have made some progress with this, but I am stuck on a strange issue...
This is my google sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10uXJVilUqAnSE_ZPlA6VKMBl0DCFRt_WqzYYl-c4Syc/edit?usp=sharing

This is my current formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({to_text(Catalog!B:J),to_text('Report_Nov 2017'!A:J)},"SELECT Col1,Col3,Col4,Col9,Col16,Col17,Col18,Col19 where Col4 != 'Retired' and Col15 MATCHES '"&textjoin("|", TRUE, Catalog!J2:J)&"'",1))
```

I am getting a result where the entries returned from Catalog are not matching the entries returned from ReportNov2017 - It just seems to be grabbing the first 25 results from Catalog instead of checking to see if the TITLE ID matches in ReportNov2017 - Any Ideas where Im going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you split the task into smaller tasks:

1. add some columns to the report sheet: `| TITLE | SUBTITLE | STATUS |`. Get their values from `Catalog (master)`. You may try `vlookup` `arrayformula` to automate this. [See the article](https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2018/01/02/vlookup-arrayformula/).
2. Then use simple `query` formula to get the rest.

Comment: Thanks for that, Max. but Report_Nov_2017 will eventually be a variable to get new reports every month and the person who will be dealing with these reports is not savvy enough to add lookups. Does your answer imply that maybe what I want to do cant be done? Nesting queries to combine non-matching tables I mean?

Comment: You may import data first, use `importrange`